# Can't install flash

Tags: software-installation, midori

I can't install flash. I used the script from the website but get the follwing error message. How do I do this?

```
Installing Flash for Midori
Press Enter to continue, or abort by pressing CTRL+C
--2015-12-23 11:56:04--  https://fpdownload.adobe.com/get/flashplayer/pdc/11.2.202.521/install_flash_player_11_linux.i386.tar.gz
Resolving fpdownload.adobe.com (fpdownload.adobe.com)... 172.233.140.76
Connecting to fpdownload.adobe.com (fpdownload.adobe.com)|172.233.140.76|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2015-12-23 11:56:04 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Answer (score 2):

I appears that Adobe have released a minor update that broke the link. The [script on howtoelementaryos.org](http://howtoelementaryos.org/how-to-install-flash-for-midori-in-elementary-os) has been repaired, but it should be noted that it was written for Luna, and may not function correctly, if at all, on Freya distributions. You should also know that [howtoelementaryos.org](http://howtoelementaryos.org) is not an official elementary OS site.

Comment: Then how do I install flash if that doesn't work?0

Comment: You probably shouldn't. Even Adobe are diminishing Flash, and have basically stopped developing it. From here on in it's just security fixes. YouTube and Netflix can both run without Flash.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the [script on howtoelementaryos.org](http://howtoelementaryos.org/how-to-install-flash-for-midori-in-elementary-os) otherwise it would not work with Midori 0.5.11 on elementary OS Freya 0.3.2 (64-bit) :

I inserted **these two lines** at the very beginning of the script :

> **sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 &&**
>
> **sudo apt-get update &&**
>
> clear &&
>
> ...
>
> fi &&

I inserted **this line** just before the last line of the script :

> **sudo apt-get install nspluginwrapper &&**
>
> nspluginwrapper -a -v -n -i

I hope that my steps are correct and that my comment may help other users.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the script the correct `nspluginwrapper` depending on your architecture. You need to install `nspluginwrapper:i386`, specifying the architecture, to install the 32 bit version on a 64 bit machine